# Delphi: Copy PDF or DOC to clipboard using TOLEContainer

Tags: delphi, clipboard

Is there a way to copy a PDF or DOC to the clipboard via the TOLEContainer?

Comment: You can't do anything in an OLEContainer that you can't do in the app being contained. As you can't copy a PDF to the clipboard in Acrobat, and you can't copy a Word document to the clipboard in Word, you can't do it in the container. (And no, when you use either of those apps to copy to the clipboard, they put the **content** in the clipboard, not the file.)